# can't get value from MySql database in my java

Tags: java, mysql

I really tried to figure out why i am not getting values from my table even thought i have check my data.it doesn't display errors but it only displays small Strings but not the long ones.

```
 private void booksTable(){
        String sql,bt,sql2,fsql="select * from Books order by title";
        int qty,loans;
        try{
            pst=conn.prepareStatement(fsql);
            rs=pst.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next()){
                booksTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
            }

            for(int row=0;row < booksTable.getRowCount();row++){
               bt=booksTable.getModel().getValueAt(row,0).toString();

               sql="select quantity from books where title = '"+bt+"'";
               pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
               rs=pst.executeQuery();
               qty=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("quantity"));
               System.out.print(row+" "+qty+"\t");
               sql2="select * from loans where BookTitle = ?";
               pst2=conn.prepareStatement(sql2);
               pst2.setString(1,bt);
               rs=pst2.executeQuery();
               if(rs.next()){
               loanTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
               loans=loanTable.getRowCount();
               }else
                   loans=0;

               System.out.println(loans);

               if((qty - loans)==0 ){
                   pst3=conn.prepareStatement("update Books set status = 'Not Available' where title = '"+bt+"'");
                   pst3.execute();

               }else{
                   pst3=conn.prepareStatement("update Books set status = 'Available' where title = '"+bt+"'");
                   pst3.execute();
               }   

            }
```

Comment: can you show us the `small Strings` and give us an idea how the `long Strings` should look like. And where in your code you expect the correct output.

Comment: for example when i search for a book like "The lion King 2" it works but when i try "Student Text Physics for Grade 10" it doesn't display i even tried to see if it returns with the system out prints i got there in my code

Comment: Have you checked if the data is retreved from the DB? We need to understand if the problem is from the DB or in the table rendering.

Comment: You are searching your String against the DB with `=`. Means it must be exactly match the String in DB. Is that the case?

Comment: yes exactly! plus i made sure that it is selected from the table with Mouse click listener which was displayed from the same table with no conditions(select * from bookTable).

Comment: log your `bt`variable. May be this will help you.

Comment: K but i forgot to mention why does it show another error which says null pointer error